# How can I keep a socket connection alive going from 1 window to another?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, chat, mean-stack

I am fairly new to socket.io but am really enjoying getting stuck into it. I am using MEAN stack and have started to play around with socket.io. I have found that the socket connection is connected to the window, so when a refresh is done, the connection is dead.

With that said, I am trying to implement a simple chat feature, similar to the one they show on the socket.io getting started tab, fairly easy. However, my connection has been created before I click on this chat button. I want the chat window to open in a new window, and provide a chat for the previously connected individuals. Is this possible and how could I implement such functionality?

I am asking from a planning point of view really so not posting my code here. My code is very similar to that of the Hello World socket.io chat app, but I just want to maintain connection from one window to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot keep a socket connection open when you load a new page into that window.  The connection belongs to a particular page and when that page is no longer active, the socket it closed and cleaned up by the browser (along with all other HTML/JS resources).  Your new page should just open the socket again and you can use some sort of cookie to identify the new connection as the same user.

Another strategy is to not load a new window and use Ajax to load new content into the current window.  This would allow you to keep the current socket alive.